# Return a function while daemon thread is working in the background (c++)

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, pthreads, daemon

I want to return function 'A' with some return value(let's say '0') while a daemon thread started running inside this function but may not finished. Is that even possible?

Comment: that really depends on how you manage the thread. It should be possible to detach the thread from the one that started it, making it basically free-living object(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just detach the thread and then return from the function.

```
int createThreadAndReturn() {
    std::thread(daemon_thread_function).detach();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it.. where the daemon plays a role here?

Comment: Is the daemon inside run_async_task()?

Comment: @user1231, Yes, I have renamed the function to be `daemon_thread_function` for clarity.